# How can I prefetch in peewee?

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I'm trying to make an optimized SQL query in order to retrieve a list of objects A with has a list of objects B with has a list of objects C and D and a many to many relation with E

I have tried to solve the problem with aggregate rows but I am having problems when there are no objects of type B or C or D.

For example I have tried this query:

```py
aa = A.alias()
query = (A.select(A, B, aa, C, D, E).join(B, peewee.JOIN_LEFT_OUTER).join(aa, peewee.JOIN_LEFT_OUTER).switch(B).join(C, peewee.JOIN_LEFT_OUTER).switch(B).join(D, peewee.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER).switch(B).join(E, peewee.JOIN_LEFT_OUTER))
```

Then, I deduplicate data with aggregate_rows. It works when there are rows of B, and C and D but when there are not, I don't get the corresponding A object with B or C or D empty list.

I have tried also to use prefetch but, when I access, A.B peewee don't run a query (Good), but, when I access A.B.C peewee runs a query (Bad).

```py
A_objects = peewee.prefetch(A,B,C,D,E)
```

I am lost, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Holy shit that's a lot of relations. Have you profiled your code and are you sure that prefetching is going to significantly improve load time? Is the outer-most loop (A) in your example a very large list? I'd suggest digging into this before jumping into trying to "optimize" your query.

> aggregate_rows()

Sounds like you're on Peewee 2.x? This is quite old and is way out of maintenance. This method was removed in 3.x because it is very inefficient in 99% of cases.

> and a many to many relation with E

This is likely the problem. A many-to-many is actually 2 tables -- a junction table with two foreign-keys, one for the source and one for the destination objects being related in a many-to-many. So if you want to try to prefetch across a many-to-many you're going to need to include the junction table. It will likely be pretty complicated.

You can see some examples of how to prefetch across a many-to-many in the tests:

https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/7bfe65cd3689e7bbd0ad5345c0454cba1b559b94/tests/manytomany.py#L278-L308

Comment: Yes I am using 2.x but I will try to update it. It is an embedded system and we have to test each change carefully.

Comment: The performance problem that we are having is the following.
We are using marshmallow-peewee and we have a schema with meta=peewee-A-model.
The context, in terms of entries, is the following: 8 entries of type A each having 250 of type B and each B having one C and one D and each B having around 5 D.

Comment: The issue comes when we try to do a SchemaA.dump(query). If the query is of type A.select() it will generate a lot of queries when it tries to access to different elements of A, for example, A.B.
I have tried to make a JOIN query with aggregate_rows but, as you mentioned before, it is not recommended and it behaviour it is not to clear.
I don't know how to proceed. It is executed on an RPI and the query takes 54 seconds something that it is unusable.
I am completely lost.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what "marshmallow" may be doing, but I'd suggest that when you're talking about 5+ joins you're probably better off ditching the magic. I doubt it would be hard to write the queries in a performant manner and just dump it into a dict.

Comment: I have answer the question below, can you tell us if it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found a solution.
As coleifer told me and as I read in the documentation, the way to proceed instead of aggregate_rows is prefetch.
In the versión I was working before making the questions was 2.x. That version fetches the prefetch data with the suffix _prefetch. For example, if A has the attribute A.something, when we prefetch it, It will be recovered in A.something_prefetch.
Marshmallow works talking directly with our model. It means, when it wants to get A.something it will query A.something not A.something_prefetch.
A.something in peewee 2.x is a SelectQuery object so it will make an SQL query instead of recovering the prefetched data.

Finally, I have upgraded the version of peewee to 3.x and now it is working. I don't know if coleifer can tell us if this answer is correct or not, but now it is working.

Hope it helps!.

Comment: Just be sure to log your queries to make sure you're not accidentally introducing any inefficiencies, but sounds correct to me.